# Vue `v-for` directive with integer range bound to component property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I am experimenting with *Vue.js* (version 2.5.16) and its `v-for` directive which should be able to repeat an element according to some integer range, according to the [official Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range). Concretely, I am trying to write a component that draws a number of circular counters based on an integer-valued property.

The following snippet, containing the hard-coded literal value `10`, does indeed render precisely ten circles: ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/vvj23rae/17/))

```
    <svg class="counter" v-for="n in 10" :key="n"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 10 10">
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5"></circle>
    </svg>
```

However, hard-coding the value is of limited utility. I have added an integer-valued property to my component as follows: (*typescript*)

```
export default Vue.extend({
    props: {
        counter: Number
    },
    ...
```

... and tried the following variants of the `v-for` directive:

- `v-for="n in counter" :key="n"` ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/vvj23rae/19/))
- `v-for="n in {counter}" :key="n"` ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/vvj23rae/20/))

But neither of them achieve a variable number of rendered circles. (*Note: I have employed the Vue developer tools to ensure that the `counter` property of the component does, in fact, hold the correct value.*)

This brings me to my question: **How do you use `v-for` with an integer range set by a property of your component?**

If this is not possible, then the integer-range support of `v-for` is indeed rather useless. How often does one want to use a hard-coded range?

However, I still want the behaviour. How would one implement it without `v-for`? I can think of several possible alternatives:

1. Write my own render function.
2. Use the `counter` property in a *computed* property that returns an array of the desired size and use `v-for` on that array.
3. Bind `v-for` to an array and hook into changes of the `counter` property to update that internal array using only array mutations that are listed on the [array change detection page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods) so that *Vue* does not discard and rebuild the entire DOM substructure on every change.

Option 1 seems like a tonne of work for such a simple use-case. Option 2 is trivially easy but I fear that it will cause *Vue* to discard and regenerate ***all*** the repeated child elements on every change. Option 3 seems like it would perform the best, if it is possible, but I don't really know how to go about it. (As I said, I am investigating *Vue* for the first time.)

What to do?

Comment: What about this http://jsbin.com/vebijiyini/edit?html,js,output ?

Comment: It does work.....https://jsfiddle.net/em90dwjs/7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to bind value to your `counter` property.Let's assume your component is called `circ`.

```
<div id="app">
  <circ :counter="10"></circ>
</div>

<template id="circ">
  <div>
    <svg class="counter" v-for="n in counter" :key="n"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 10 10">
         <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/vebijiyini/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yes! That's the answer. See working: https://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/vvj23rae/33/ and not working: https://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/vvj23rae/19/. And the only difference is that, in one, I was setting the property directly (`value="..."`) and, in the other, I was binding it: (`v-bind:value="..."` or `:value="..."`). I guess that this is a bug because, for everything else, it is allowed to set the value directly. Only for `v-for` is it not working.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [`v-for` docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range), you can use `v-for` with a numeric range directly:

> `v-for` can also take an integer. In this case it will repeat the template that many times.

So you can just use `v-for="n in counter"`, as in the example below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 10
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.counter {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h3>Select number of circles</h3>
    <input type="number" v-model.number="counter" />
  </div>
  <svg class="counter" v-for="n in counter" :key="n" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, if you're doing it this way, it does work. (it also works with defaulted properties: https://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/vvj23rae/7/) but it doesn't work with components with properties unless the property is bound. Hence I am accepting Belman Bedak's answer as the answer.

Comment: The code in my answer is just the simplest way I thought of to reproduce a `v-for` using a numeric range - I didn't realise that there was any issue with passing a property to a child. I guess that in your comment you are referring to the need to use `:counter="counter"`? Either way, you are of course welcome to accept whichever answer you find most useful.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/vvj23rae/19/) , you are passing the prop named `value` as

```
<counter-component value="14" />
```

You are not dynamically binding the `value` prop using `v-bind` or `:` (shorthand)

So the number `14` you are passing as `value` is evaluated as a string

So bind the prop to consider it as a number

```
 counter-component v-bind:value="14" />
```

Or

```
counter-component :value="14" />
```

Here is your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvj23rae/35/)

Comment: Thanks. This is correct. I was fooled by the fact that the interpolation in the `h3` *was* working, even with `value` set directly, but the `v-for` was not. Belman Bedak also posted the same information in his answer.